# What is the easiest way to get "Walking in a winter wonderland"?

Tags: steam, achievements

There is a prize on Steam for getting the "Walking in a winter wonderland" achievement in the Greed Corp. game. What is the easiest way to get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Click "Create Battle" when the game starts
2. Add 3 other LOCAL players so there are four players total including you.
3. Pick the "Northern Steps" map - this is a winter map
4. For every player who isn't you, create a harvester on the tile in which they are standing. Go to the next turn.
5. On the next turn, self destruct each harvester (you should have no harvesters except for all other players).
6. You should win and get the achievement now.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I pick the right map and I do win (my player not the 'friend of myplayer'). Still don't get an achievement of any kind :/

Comment: Never mind, season setting was random had to re-create until i got a winter setting.

Answer (score 0):

Taken directly from http://steamtreasurehunt.wikia.com/wiki/Winter_Objectives

Start a match, and pick local players for player 2 and 3. It should say "buddy of " or "friend of " for player 2 and 3 names. Pick the map Angoran Mountains, which you can't actually do until you've unlocked it, but far be it from this guide to actually document such arcane processes. Anyway, once you've figured out how to unlock the map you need, which for all we know could take a month of playtime, make sure that the center tile is covered in snow. If it's not, quit and remake the game. Since you control all 3 players, fast forward through your own turns, and build a harvester each for players 2 and 3 - the harvester will eventually destroy the ground, the units will fall through and you'll be victorious. Player 1 (you) won't always go first.

I haven't yet tried this myself since my Greed Corp is acting up, but that should work.

PS: as a question to the asker.. do you know how far you have to go into the game to unlock the Angoran Mountains?

Comment: Welcome to the site! You should post the question in your P.S. as a separate question using the Ask Question button in the top right.

Comment: Just for reference, as the question has not been asked separately yet: just pick Mokosh Dam until it gets randomly picked as a snow map.